# Is this method for evaluating this complex limit correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am trying to calculate
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-zt}$$
where $z$ is complex and $Re(z)>0.$ This means that if we define $z=x+iy$, then $x>0.$

So

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-(x+iy)t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-xt}\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-iyt}=e^{-\infty}\left(\cos(\pm\infty)+i\sin(\pm\infty)\right)=0\cdot\text{number}=0$$
Is this argument correct?

Comment: The value of $e^{i\theta}$ is bounded by $|e^{i\theta}|=1$ and the limit is zero.

Comment: Would this be correct too?

Comment: Since $e^{iy}$ is bounded the limit is not an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such $\cos(\infty)$.

Rather, one can do like $|e^{-zt}|=|e^{-xt}|\cdot|e^{-iyt}|=e^{-xt}\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ because $\text{Re}(z)=x>0$.

Comment: Thanx! But isn't $\lim_{t\to\infty}\cos(t)$ any number in $[-1,1]$? Why is it wrong to say that $e^{-\infty}$ is multiplied by a finite complex number and so the result is $0$?

Comment: To be strictly speaking, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\cos t$ does not exist because it has different limit points.